# Crystal Report by using CRExport via PHP

Tags: php, command-line, crystal-reports

I'm trying to generate a crystal report via a php script.
I was able to successfully use [crexport](http://www.rainforestnet.com/crystal-reports-exporter/index.htm) to generate a pdf report. However when I try to execute the script via php's exec command I get this error.

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mamobile\crexport -F c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mamobile\reports\customer.rpt -O c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mamobile\output\test.pdf -E pdf -S testdb 

Crystal Reports Exporter Command Line Utility. Version 2.1.11.1103
Copyright(c) 2011 Rainforest Software Solution http://www.rainforestnet.com

Misc Error: Load report failed.
Type "crexport -?" for help
```

It works fine via the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely but is your report by any chance still open in the Crystal Designer when you were running this script? I was getting this error when the .rpt file was open.

Comment: I am not in charge of making the reports. I do not have Crystal Designer installed on my dev machine.

Comment: Oh ok. Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 0):

it works.
remember to not be with the open rpt file in graphics editor

```
$output = '';
$command = 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mamobile\crexport -F c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mamobile\reports\customer.rpt -O c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mamobile\output\test.pdf -E pdf -S testdb';
exec($command, $output);
var_dump($output);
```